# Python: Checking for a missing arithmetic operator between two values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Somewhat new to programming and Python. I am writing a program to accept a string input from user, put the string into a list and the program will run through checks on the list to see if the expression is valid. If valid, the program will use eval the string and output the answer.

The problem is that I am unable to figure out how code the check for the missing arithmetic operator between two values.

I got an idea that in the function, I need a for loop to go through the list, compare the current value in the list against the next value in the list and if both don't match against a operator list which includes the operators, this means that I am missing an operator.

So I think I have to write a if statement inside the for loop to do this. I also need the if statement to ignore the parentheses(if any) in the list. However, I am unable to figure how to code that if statement.

Am I doing it the right way or is there an easier or better way to do this?

I've included a simplified sample of my code below. Thanks.

```
def missingCheck(myList, operatorList):

  for currentToken in myList:
    if #not able to figure out this part
    count = myList.index(currentToken)
    strLeft = " ".join(myList[0:count])
    strRight = " ".join(myList[count:])
    print("Missing operator between {} and {}".format(strLeft, strRight))
  return

def main():
  myList = []
  operatorList = ["+", "-", "/", "//", "*"]

  strInput = str("( 33 ) ( 1 )")  #hardcoded for checking, values differentiated with space
  myList = strInput.split(" ")

  missingCheck(myList, operatorList)

  #simplifed program for testing, there will be a eval(strInput) later to parse the string if the input is correct
  #Program would actually ask user for input.
  #strInput = str("3 4")      <--- other sample input
  #strInput = str(1 2 + 3)    <--- other sample input
main()
```

Comment: How is the input string from the user formatted?  It looks like space delimited string tokens.  Is the program supposed to check for every possible combination of symbols?  If so, what are you going to do about "(" and "33", for which there is no operator possible that can work?  Is "" one of your operators (which would alleviate that problem) ..?

Comment: You're going to have to handle errors from the `eval()` anyway (division by zero, for example) - might as well let that catch syntax errors, too.

Comment: The input string from user is formatted with a space in between each value. The user will input only values that are either numbers, parentheses and the 5 arithmetic operator in the operatorList( + - / // *). I was thinking part of the if statement need to include currentToken ! = "(" and currentToken ! = ")" to account for the parentheses. As for the numbers, I'm not what I can do about that. Please advise. If "" is in my operatorList, what problem will it alleviate? I'm not sure what "" would do when included in the operatorList.

Comment: @jasonharper, eval() can catch syntax errors yup, but for reasons, I have to do it the hard way. I have to catch this error (missing arithmetic operator) with a function.

Comment: You can use a variable to hold either the last seen token or a state. If e. g. encountering open parens, state would become "expect expression" meaning either number or another open parens must follow. After a number, one would expect either operator or closing parens. State can be a number chosen from some defined constants. Additionally the parens balance must be checked of course.